# What is the standard method of slicing a photoshop document?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, slices

Is there any industry standard method of slicing a PSD to convert to HTML? Because I use marquee tool rather than slices.

At times there is design where slicing cannot do the job like if you need 2 slices one with a layer hidden and one with a layer visible. Do we have to use marquee tool there? Or is there any other technique?

Answer (score 3):

I drag guides, change the Crop tool to the Slice tool, and click on "Make Slides From Guides." If necessary, you then change the Slice tool to the Select Slice tool, and that allows you to select several slices and combine them.

Your layers are not affected. So you Save For Web with the first state, turn your layer on or off, and then Save For Web with the second state.

Comment: Also you can export only the affected slices after the state changes on the subsequent Save for Web saves.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach

- use the marquee tool
- select what you want to crop
- copy merged (ctrl + shift + C)
- open a new file with ctrl + N
- it will automatically set it's dimensions to whatever you have in your clipboard
- press enter
- paste (ctrl + V)
- save for web and devices (ctrl + alt + shift + S)

I generally find this approach beter, as I tend to slice just what I need while coding the design.

Comment: this is what I usually do