# How Do I make a simple webpage out of image, need some pointers

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design

I have an image and its source in photoshop and Adobe illustrator format.

I know some programing, PHP, HTML. But I have never created a simple webpage using an image or adobe products.

I'm also overwhelmed by the amount to blogs, websites and video available there. I want you guys to give me pointers where I can find the latest resources to learn this.

I want to be able to insert an email form into the image make little changes.

Give me some pointer to get me going.

Comment: "I want to be able to insert an email form into the image make little changes." what you want to do?? show us your image this would be easy to help,and easy to figure out that what is to be sliced and whats is not..

Comment: you have an image or psd file?

Comment: I have both image as well as psd, but for a simple banner images, it has tons of layers.

Comment: so you can slice your layers as well,the layer which you dont want to appear in your banner unchek them,and if still not getting this upload your psd i'll do it for you ;)

Comment: Thank you Jack very much for offering to do it, but I wanted to learn this and your links are pretty nice. I got around to do things, I want, but its very crappy.

Comment: bhai every single thing is crappy in start, just follow tutorials soon you'll be very good in all this,and on this site we have lots of question regarding how to's just check them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already know programming, all you have to slice image parts to use in your design,

so i am considering  this question as  **how to slice images for your web project**

If you have Psd you can slice your design to get your work page.

with the help of photoshop:

`open your image/psd in photoshop`

`Select the element which you want to use in your project`

`And slice with the help of slice tool` a point to point tutorial listed below

- [Slicing my layout](http://www.entheosweb.com/photoshop/slice.asp)
- [How to Slice an image/psd in photoshop](http://www.elated.com/articles/slicing-in-photoshop/)

There are several example of showing how to convert psd to html ( You can learn how they slice and use different part of design ).

- [20+ Best Tutorials to Convert Psd to Html/CSS](http://dzineblog.com/2009/04/tutorials-psd-to-html.html)

In above link there are types of complete method of creating webpage form PSD/image do follow the same to get going.

A very good answer of similar question : [Method of slicing Photoshop document](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/200/what-is-the-standard-method-of-slicing-a-photoshop-document)

Hope this will help, and sorry if its vague :|